# Use md5_file() function with accent on filename

Tags: php

In my PHP script, I use the `md5_file()` function to return an md5 key for each analyzed file.

However, when a file has an accent in the filename, the `md5_file()` function cannot read the file.

```
//filename: Flash_Conquête_Galactic.txt
Warning: md5_file(.....): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
```

I tried to use the `iconv()` function or the `utf8_encode()` function, but both had absolutely no result.

Is there any way to fix this problem without modifying the filename?

Comment: Please, post filename example.

Comment: what charset is your underlying OS using? blindly encoding your filename into other charsets is pointless, unless you what WHAT charset is required.

Comment: yes, you can use it without modifying filename...

Comment: For UTF8 you can try `$filename = mb_convert_encoding($filename, 'UTF-8');`

Comment: @Plamen Nikolov : Thx, but nop. Always the same problem.

Comment: @LevB :
Example : Flash_Conquête_Galactic.txt

Comment: @Marc B : Windows ( 1252 ) classic charset. I'am not sure if that answer your question ?

Comment: then doing utf8 encoding on the string is essentially corrupting your string. utf8 != win1252

Comment: Some background: http://evertpot.com/filesystem-encoding-and-php/ (hope it helps)

Comment: @Evert : Thx, i go reading that. 

Oh and i forgot, md5_file() works when I input the accentuated file name directly in the code source. ( For testing ).

Comment: @MarcB : Oki, i tried to change charset UTF-8 to ANSI and it work fine now.

Thx for your help and thx at all for your contributions.

Answer (score -1):

It looks the $filename may have been UTF-8 encoded somehow, possibly by your IDE/editor.

Try this...

```
    // Your filename
    $filename = 'Flash_Conquête_Galactic.txt';

    // Decode the string to ISO-8859-1.
    $filename = utf8_decode($filename);

    // Generate a hash of the files contents.
    echo md5_file($filename);
```

Comment: Thx, but it's ok now. Look my last commentary on the first post. MarcB has given the solution. utf8 != win1252. If i use ANSI rather than UTF-8, my problem is resolved.